# instagram retrieve hashtag images - update June 1

Tags: permissions, instagram, hashtag

I am aware of the update to Instagram apis. I have read through the documentation regarding fetching hashtag images. I'm confused regarding 2 points -

1. They have a section "Endpoints", which gives the url for fetching images using tags - **https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN**
2. At the same time, when i try to submit for review (under Permissions Review section), in order to get access token, i get this message -
   "This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display)."

The 2nd point makes me believe that Instagram has stopped sharing hashtag images to apis, at the same time i can find a lot of widgets still fetching hashtag images. How do they do that? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 2nd point makes me believe that Instagram has stopped sharing hashtag images to apis,

Correct. Instagram has made business decision to block most developers from accessing this content.

> at the same time i can find a lot of widgets still fetching hashtag images.

This doesn't tell you much. They might have gotten their app approved for other purposes. Also it appears that Instagram has made some exceptions for big apps (like Tinder). Life is not fair.

> How do they do that? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

You probably cannot. 99% of the use cases are not allowed and so they will reject your app if you try to submit it. Read this short article about [what you can and cannot do with the new Instagram API](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.psynexzi3)

Answer (score 0):

The other widgets you are talking about probably have presented Instagram with one of the [valid use cases](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/) to fetch the data. They are able to get only the public content. This new restriction is probably a business decision. If you would still want to get the data you are looking for, you shopuld possibly go to a third party data provider who sell such data

Comment: What do we need to become a company who could sell such data?